# Secret API key for accessing Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My aim is to restrict access to API for client applications by specifying API Key. Various services allow you to access their API by means of secret Key, which you have to get in order to perfom requests.

Note: this is not related to user auth.

Is there any straightforward solution to do this in django rest framework? Or just to pass the key in request header and then manually handle it?

Regards

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? I wonder if you can share an example maybe? Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the `TokenAuthentication` class, as documented [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#tokenauthentication).

You'll also want to setup appropriate permissions, probably using the [IsAuthenticated](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions#isauthenticated) class.

**Edit**: Apologies - re-reading you post it looks like you want a global secret key, not a per-user one. I'd suggest a [custom permission class](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions#custom-permissions) that checks for the request header and fails if it's not present/not correct.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for creating such wonderful tool  like django-rest-framework :) 

It seems to be exactly what I was searching for. I will try to implement custom permission and come back with it here. 

Many thanks again :)

Comment: I think @ArazAbishov is aiming to setup a system similar to FaceBooks API - an alternative/extension to user auth - so a "client" can create an application on his system, then send requests on the behalf of users, but still tied to their application, limited to the permissions that app is granted

Answer (score 7):

There is a third party app now for this purpose called [django-rest-framework-api-key](https://github.com/manosim/django-rest-framework-api-key).

Comment: According to their github page, it does only support python upto `3.5`. The latest versions like `3.8`, `3.9` and `3.10` are not supported.